# Symfony 3 does not injects EntityManager to service

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony

I use symfony 3.1.

I'm trying to inject EntityManager to my service class. I did all just like in documentation but still keep getting exception.

```
    [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]                                                                                                     
  Type error: Argument 1 passed to AppBundle\Writers\TeamsWriter::__construct() must be an instance of Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager, none given, called in /ho  
  me/admin_u/Documents/test_project/src/AppBundle/Command/ParseMatchesCommand.php on line 54
```

Why it doesn't injects doctrine in service class?

**Service**

```
private $entity_manager;

    /**
     * TeamsWriter constructor.
     * @param EntityManager $entity_manager
     */
    public function __construct(EntityManager $entity_manager)
    {
        $this->entity_manager = $entity_manager;
    }
```

**Services.yml**

```
services:
 teams_writer:
    class: AppBundle\Writers\TeamsWriter
    arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"]
```

**Service usage**

```
protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
    $parser = new TeamsParser();
    $data = $parser->execute();
    $writer = new TeamsWriter();
    $writer->store($data);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You didn't use service but the class only. To use service in your command,  extend it by `ContainerAwareCommand`, and you can call yours service from it:

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\ContainerAwareCommand;

class MyCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{
    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $writer = $this->getContainer()->get('teams_writer');
```

Comment: Or inject the parser and writer directly into the command and avoid the need to inject the container.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by @malcolm, you need to register the command as a service as well.

Since **Symfony 3.3** is about to be relased in few days, I will use [its new Dependency Injection features](https://www.tomasvotruba.cz/blog/2017/05/07/how-to-refactor-to-new-dependency-injection-features-in-symfony-3-3/). I will only rewrite your code you already posted:

**Services.yml**

```
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true # all services here will be autowired = no need for manual service naming in constructor
        autoconfigure: true # this will add tags to all common services (commands, event subscribers, form types...)

    AppBundle\Writers\TeamsWriter: ~ # short notation for a service
    AppBundle\Parsers\TeamsParser: ~

    AppBundle\Command\YourCommand: ~
```

**Service usage**

```
use AppBundle\Parsers\TeamsParser;
use AppBundle\Writers\TeamsWriter;

final class YourCommand extends Command
{

    // ... use constructor injection to get your dependencies

    public function __construct(TeamsWriter $teamsWriter, TeamsParser $teamsParser)
    {
        $this->teamsWriter = $teamsWriter;
        $this->teamsParser = $teamsParser;
        parent::__construct(); // this is need if this is console command, to setup name and description
        // kinda hidden dependency but it is the way it works now
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $data = $this->teamsParser->execute();
        $this->teamsWriter->store($data);
    }    
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Hm You need to use `Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;` in your TeamsWriter,